# Vertical Sit-up Bench

Tags: exercise-equipment, sit-ups

I have been searching the internet for this piece of equipment. I like doing that style of sit-ups. It doesn't tighten my hamstrings or compress my back.

Does anyone know what this equipment is called?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The title of this question describes such a piece of equipment pretty well. I don't think a vertical one like in your picture has its own name, some just decline further than others. Just search 'vertical sit-up bench' or even just 'sit-up bench' and go for one that advertises a 90 degree decline.

Comment: I did that out of curiosity when I first saw the question and I couldn't find that anywhere. There was just a failed Kickstarter. The image is from a Men's Health article. I imagine commercial gyms wouldn't want this because it looks pretty dangerous.

Comment: @DeeV - I did find this - https://www.fitnessgizmos.com/uready-vertical-situp-bench/ - But that looks very sketchy, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: @JohnP. Yeah that was the failed Kickstarter. https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/uready/uready/?